# Adding Legend to Time Lapse in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, legend, video

I am trying to add a Legend to a time lapse video. In my final print I have an image collection and the video specifications are already defined.

```
print(ui.Thumbnail(ImageCollection, videoArguments)); //print gif
print(ImageColletion.getVideoThumbURL(videoArguments));
```

is there any way to add a continuous (gradient) legend as an RGB object (or text) using visualization properties?